# Question on counting

Tags: combinatorics

> If 8 identical whiteboards must be divided among 4 schools, how many divisions are possible?

For this, the answer is 11C3, and I know this is obtained using stars and bars counting method. However, why can't you simply do $4^8$, as for each white board there are 4 choices as to which school receives it.

Comment: I think the point is that we shouldn't distinguish between (for instance) [boards 1,2 go to school A boards 3,4 go to school B] and  [boards 1,2 go to school B boards 3,4 go to school A]. These are counted as distinct if we do $4^8$ but in both scenarios schools A and B each get 2 boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be 4^8 if the whiteboards were not identical.

You want to use the [Stars and Bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) method here. You can divide 8 boards to 4 schools in exactly the same number of ways as 12 boards to 4 school if every school has to get at least one. You just give one to each school and then divide the rest without any constraints. Now draw 12 dots on a paper. There will be 11 gaps between them. Each gap represents a place you can put a "divider". You need to put in 3 dividers to create 4 groups, and you can see that there are 11C3 ways to do that. Deduct one from each school's whiteboard count when dividing the 12 dots to see how many they would get in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as solving for the number of non-negative integer solutions of the equation $x + y + z + t = 8$ with $x, y, z, t \geq 0$. The answer is: $8 + 4 - 1\choose 4 - 1$ = $11 \choose 3$ = $165$ possible divisions.

Comment: Yeah, I know that -- my question was on why you can't do $4^8$ which was answered by Frederick in his comment.